# Lambda Deployments with SAM CLI is too long

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, command-line-interface, sam

I am working with SAM CLI to deploy my serverless functions.
I have more than 15 functions right now and every time when I need to do some changes in one of my function I need to wait too long to finish the whole process of the deployment (~6-8 min).

Is there any improvements to decrease this time? Maybe I can deploy only one function, not all?

Thanks! Have a good day.

Comment: Can you please add what's taking so long during your deployment? The CloudFormation console shows you detailed information about that.

Comment: @Dunedan: I am also facing the same issue and I see that the upload phase is taking really long time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not break out each Lambda function into its own template (and therefore stack) so you can update and deploy that one function/stack at a time?